# How to avoid losing focus after starting an asynchronous process?

Tags: async, subprocess, x-window

The lisp function `start-process` is meant to start an asynchronous
subprocess, namely a process running independently of Emacs
itself.

I have noticed that, under my GNOME desktop
environment, when my subprocess opens another window, the focus
is transferred to that other window, even if the mouse pointer
remains over the portion of my emacs window visible outside the
subprocess window.

I believe I am able to programmatically transfer the focus back
to the emacs window using the Unix utility `wmctrl`, but for the sake of elegance, I would
much prefer to avoid doing this extra work.

Hence my question:

**Question.** Is it possible to start an asynchronous process whose window does not steal the focus from Emacs?

PS:  I have attempted to replace `start-process` with `call-process` (with the `DESTINATION` parameter set to 0), but the problem persists!

Comment: I think this is a question about the desktop environment, not about emacs. You should probably ask the question in the Unix & Linux SE.

Comment: This is definitely a question about configuring your window manager, and not anything to do with Emacs.

Comment: Thanks to Nick and @db48x for your suggestions.  You both are quite likely on the right path, but unfortunately I wasn't able to follow your lead.  My Gnome window manager offers 2 options for creating new windows, namely "smart" and "strict" but neither changes that undesirable behavior.

Comment: Yea,  Gnome has gotten a lot less configurable over the years. You should look into alternative window managers. There are hundreds of them, and most of them will work as drop–in replacements for the Gnome window manager (called mutter, iirc) while allowing you to retain the rest of the Gnome Desktop Environment. Perhaps one or more of them will behave how you want.