# Transfer focus to started asynchronous process

Tags: window, shell, process, focus

I have the opposite issue from [How to avoid losing focus after starting an asynchronous process?](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/68204/how-to-avoid-losing-focus-after-starting-an-asynchronous-process).  I would like to call `start-process` and have the resulting window be focused.

Specifically, I am calling `dragon-drop` and would like its popup window focused so I can close it with `ESC` if needed. Neither `start-process` nor `call-process` did the trick:

```lisp
(defun xf/dragon ()
  "Share file from current buffer via dragon."
  (interactive)
  (apply 'start-process
         `("dragon" nil
         "dragon-drop" "-a" "-x"
           ,@(dired-get-marked-files)
           ,(unless (dired-get-marked-files)
             (or (buffer-file-name)
                 (image-dired-original-file-name)
                 default-directory)
             )))
  )
```

Can I do anything from within Emacs about this, or do I have to configure my WM?